# How can I import data from excel to postgres- many to many relationship

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql, csv

I'm creating a web application and I encountered a problem with importing data to a table in a postgress database.
I have excel with id_b and id_cat(books id and categories id) books have several categories and categories can be assigned to many books, excel looks like this:
[excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHoPb.png)

It has 30 000 records.

I have a problem how to import it into the database(Postgres). The table for this data has two columns:
id_b and id_cat. I wanted to export this data to csv in this way, each book has to be assigned a category identifier (e.g., book with identifier 1 should appear 9 times because it has 9 categories assigned to it and so on)- but I can't do it easily. It should looks like this:
[correct data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq7HI.png)
 Does anyone know any way to get data in this form?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is it about connecting Excel and Postgres?  Is it about the particular data transformations?  It seems rather broadly phrased.

Comment: Hi,I think that i have a problem with transform data, so the question is about transforming the data into such a format that it is possible to import them into postgres.can I add something to get some tips that allows me to get the data in the right format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your excel sheet format has a large number of columns, which also depends on the number of categories, and SQL isn't well adapted to that.

The simplest option would be to:

Export your excel data as CSV.

Use a python script to read it using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and output COPY-friendly tab-delimited format.

Load this into the database (or INSERT directly from python script).

Something like that...

```
import csv

with open('bookcat.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            id = row[0].strip()
            categories = row[1:]
            for cat in categories:
                cat = cat.strip()
                if cat:
                    print("%s\t%s" % (id, cat))
```

csv output version:

```
import csv

with open('bookcat.csv') as csvfile, open("out.csv","w") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            id = row[0].strip()
            categories = row[1:]
            for cat in categories:
                cat = cat.strip()
                if cat:
                    writer.writerow((id, cat))
```

If you need a specific csv format, check the docs of csv module.

Comment: How can I put such transformed data into a csv file?

Comment: Thank u so much!